# Using External Classes method as action for NSMenuItem?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsmenuitem

First time poster and very novice swift user. I've came up against a problem of using an external classes method as an action for a NSMenuItem. I've set up a new class called NewDocument have the method newDoc.

I want to use this method as an action for a NSMenuItem. However, when I use it, the menu item is greyed out? Even when I set the target to NewDocument, it still wont work.

Any guidance or help would be very much appreciated.

```
//Creating Instance of class
let createNewDocument = NewDocument()

//Use selector to declare method as action
let menuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "New", action: #selector(createNewDocument.newDoc), keyEquivalent: "")

//Set target to new instance of class
menuItem.target = createNewDocument
```

NewDocument Class

```
class NewDocument: NSObject {
    @objc func newDoc() {
        // new document logic
    }
}
```

[image: Example of output]

Comment: Have a read through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target%E2%80%93action . Selectors are just special strings which contain the name of a method. The `#selector` syntax in Swift is used to have the compiler generate the string for you, to try to protect you from writing a typo. The method you want to use has to belong on an class. `createNewDocument` is an instance, not a class. You probably want `#selector(NewDocument.newDoc)`.

Comment: Is `createNewDocument` released because it goes out of scope?

Answer (score 0):

- The target is the instance of the class – `createNewDocument`
- The selector is the type + method – `#selector(NewDocument.newDoc)`

Comment: Ok, still not sure. Should I be using #selector then? Could you kindly clarify what you mean by type in this instance?

Comment: The type of the class is `NewDocument`.